# How can I simulate the iOS 5 four-finger app-change swipe feature?

Tags: ios5, swipe-gesture

I don't have access to an iPad running iOS 5 (and since Apple doesn't allow downgrading(!), I'm not going to upgrade my test device).

How can I use the simulator to test the 4-finger app-change swipe functionality that's new to iOS 5? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS4.3 you could enable "Multitasking Gestures" from Settings > General so long as your iPad is in developer mode (Xcode > Organiser > Devices > [Your iPad] > Use for development) for which you need an iOS dev subscription, I think.

Apple only enabled this for developers and iOS5 no longer allows this for the iPad 1 (even for developers, which is very frustrating).

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/03/14/enable-ios-4-3-gesture-controls-on-your-ipad-with-free-xcode-3-d/

---

On the Simulator you can simulate the 4-finger app-change swipe by double tapping the home button and then selecting the next application. The application order and transition are different but the functionality is basically the same. I'm not sure exactly what about this feature you are trying to test?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately, I'm running my iPad with 4.2.1 and need to keep it that way for testing all of our other apps.

Comment: Of course, re-enabling on iOS5 is a simple Cydia Tweak. Also, you can re-enable the multitouch gestures on iPad 1 with iOS5 without jailbreaking. The technique actually uses redsn0w, just instead of telling it to jailbreak and install Cydia, it installs the single tweak without a jailbreak. [instructions](http://cydiahelp.com/enable-multitasking-gestures-ipad-1-ios-5-and-display-mirroring-without-jailbreak/)

Comment: @TRedman - you should be able to use the Xcode developer mode then, since you're still on iOS 4. Unless you are avoiding "Use for development" on your test device for some reason?

Comment: @Ian, I use the iPad for development with XCode. It's running 4.2.1, which doesn't appear to have the multi-touch gesture available in General > Settings.

Comment: @TRedman My bad, I misread the version you were running. 4.2.1 does not have the 4-finger gesture code at all, so it can't be enabled. Until you can run a more recent version of iOS on the device, I don't think you'll be able to do this at all.